# How to permanently set the timestamp to the exact message time (instead of elapsed time)

Tags: slack

After some number of hours the message timestamps are changed to elapsed time. I do really need the *actual* local time of the messages. How can this be adjusted?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a way to change this in settings, but you can see the actual time with a little effort.

For the **slack app on a mobile phone** it converts to the exact time if I open the thread.

For the **slack app on a PC** I can hover over the "*xx hours/minutes ago*" text with the mouse cursor and it shows the time. It still says "yesterday" for the previous day rather than the date, but further back it also gives you calendar date.

The hover popup looks like this on PC:
[image]